# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException

Tags: java, hibernate, exception

i have these Pojos:

```
public class ParticipantPojo implements Serializable
.....
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "participant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo> identificationNumbers;
```

and

```
public class ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo implements Serializable
 ......
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTICIPANT", nullable = false)
private ParticipantPojo participant;
```

When i want to create a new participant with

```
 ParticipantPojo pojo= new ParticipantPojo ();
 ...
 Set<ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo> identSet = new HashSet<ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo>();
 ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo identInfo= new ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo();
 identInfo.setType("xyz");
 identInfo.setNumber(12345);
 identSet.add(identInfo);
 pojo.setIdentificationNumbers(identSet);
```

and save it

```
 session.save(pojo);
```

i get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value: de.seeburger.marktpartnerdaten.database.pojo.ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo.participant
```

In a blog i found the solution to set nullable=true at

```
@JoinColumn(name = "PARTICIPANT", nullable = false)
```

but that is not what i want (participant should not be null!)...setting nullable=true create another exception

```
org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: de.seeburger.marktpartnerdaten.database.pojo.ParticipantPojo
```

I think the problem is, that Hibernate does not save the participant and take the ID to save participantIdentificationNumber...but i found no solution for my exception :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have created a bi-directional relationship with `ParticipantPojo` acting as the defining side (with the `mappedBy` property in the `@OneToMany` annotation). The `ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo` is the owning side of the relationship, and you must register the instance of the defining side on the owning side.

So, you will have to register the `ParticipantPojo` instance as follows:

```
ParticipantPojo pojo= new ParticipantPojo ();
...
Set<ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo> identSet = new HashSet<ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo>();
ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo identInfo= new ParticipantIdentificationNumberPojo();
identInfo.setType("xyz");
identInfo.setNumber(12345);
identInfo.setParticipantPojo(pojo); // <-- Registering the instance on the owning side.
identSet.add(identInfo);
pojo.setIdentificationNumbers(identSet);
```

Ideally you must register the relationship in both directions even though you have declared a bi-directional relationship. Hibernate will however make things easy if you set the value  on the owning side, as that is the side that contains the foreign key; once you think about this, you'll realize the reason for the second error message that you are getting - foreign keys cannot be null.